# Xamarin SearchBar remove cancel button on Android

Tags: xamarin.android

How can I remove the cancel button in the search bar on Android?

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT, I couldn't to resolve it

Comment: Have you tried my code below?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT, Yes

Comment: Please see my update. And if you have any other concerns, we could discuss it under my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach could be:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    app:closeIcon="@null"/>
```

If you need to disable its function, try to achieve it using code behind:

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView searchView = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView);
ImageView mCloseButton = (ImageView)searchView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_close_btn);
mCloseButton.Enabled = false;
mCloseButton.SetImageDrawable(null);
```

We need to use `Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView` here for retrieving the button or it will get null when using `SearchView`.

### Update

I uploaded a simple sample here: https://github.com/landl0526/SearchViewSample.git

Here is the effect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's helped me